# Is there a simple way to substitute a tick in the axis environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

Is there a simple way to substitute a tick in the axis environment? I want to replace the tick defined by `data` (that is, `xtick = data`).

Below is an example where I *add* an extra tick. Since I'm adding, I am not substituting, and I want to know how to substitute.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
date,pct
44755,0.01925374
44756,0.01925374
44757,0.01925374
44768,0.018989264
44769,0.018989264
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
         ymin = -0.07, ymax =0.11,
         %
        xtick  = data,  
        xticklabel style={ rotate=45},
        extra x ticks={44757, 44765},
        extra x tick labels={special1, special2},
        extra x tick style={tick label style={red}},    
        scaled ticks=false,
     ]
        \addplot[
        blue, const plot,
    ] table [x=date, y=pct, col sep = comma]{data.csv};
    \end{axis}
      
      \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that lets you specify which ticks to replace based on their *x*-value in `\replaceTheseTicks`. In this example, the ticks with an *x*-value of 44757 and 44768 have been replaced with "Alice" and "Bob," respectively. A warning, though: This code only works with integers.

[image: A graph of the original code. The x-axis contains the ticks 44755, 44756, Alice, Bob, 44769.]

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
date, pct
44755,0.01925374
44756,0.01925374
44757,0.01925374
44768,0.018989264
44769,0.018989264
\end{filecontents}

% Comma-separated list of ticks you want to replace
\def\replaceTheseTicks{44757,44768}

\def\replaceTick{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\tick}
  \def\replaceHere{}
  \foreach\xValue in \replaceTheseTicks{
    \ifnum\xValue=\result
      \gdef\replaceHere{T}
    \fi
  }
  \if T\replaceHere
    {}
  \else
    \axisdefaultticklabel
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin  = -0.07,
    ymax  = 0.11,
    xtick = data,
    xticklabel = {\replaceTick},
    xticklabel style={rotate = 90},
    extra x ticks=\replaceTheseTicks,
    extra x tick labels={Alice, Bob},
    extra x tick style={tick label style={red}},    
    scaled ticks=false,
  ]
  \addplot[blue, const plot] table [x=date, y=pct, col sep = comma]{data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```